# Bonitasoft can't login as administrator

Tags: bonita

I have the following problem

I am trying to login as Administrator with username: platformAdmin and password: platform, but no use. 
It writes

> "Unable to log in. Please check your username and password."

After the wizard installation I didn't change anything. Also I have noticed, that inside `C:\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.2.2\workspace\tomcat`, there isn't the bonita folder.... What can I do for login??

If you have farther questions, just ask.

Thx for your time

Answer (score 3):

Platform administrator account is an account that can only be used to access platform REST API.

If you need to login on Bonita BPM Portal as administrator (for example to create user account) you need to use the tenant administrator account. Default user name and password for tenant administrator account are: `install`/`install`.

Multi-tenant is available for Bonita BPM Subscription users and so multiple tenant administrator accounts exists.

You can get information about how to change administrator user name and password in the [documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/first-steps-after-setup-0#reset_pw).

Note that it is not recommended to customize Studio embedded Bonita BPM platform. You should rather install for example a Bonita BPM + Tomcat bundle.

Answer (score -1):

try to reinstall it may help i problem further occurs please post